# How can I separate the output of the web service?

Tags: php, web-services, pointers

I get this result from web service in php code:

```
> stdClass Object (
>     [Post_Added_Record_ByMenuIDResult] => stdClass Object
>         (
>             [HTMLStructure] => ثبت انجام شد
>             [IsAuthenticated] => 1
>             [MenuID] => 1191
>             [Password] => 
>             [PersonID] => 27598
>             [PersonalityID] => 31413
>             [RecordValues] => 
>             [RoleID] => 5
>             [Sexuality_Title] => m
>             [UserName] => mr.piri
>         ) )
```

I want to get the opposite phrase in [HTMLStructure]. in this example : ثبت انجام شد

```
if (strstr( $result, 'HTMLStructure' ) ) {
       $HTMLStructurePos=strpos( $result, '[HTMLStructure] =>' );
       echo $HTMLStructurePos;
       $IsAuthenticatedPos=strpos( $result, '            [IsAuthenticated]' );
       echo $IsAuthenticatedPos;
       $result2 = substr($result, $HTMLStructurePos, $IsAuthenticatedPos);
  echo "<pre>";
   print_r($result2);
   echo "</pre>";
} else {
  echo "Not found";
}
```

but i get

> Not found

in the out put.

I think this is a structure and I have to get the value with the pointer.But does anyone know how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved this problem by this code:

```
foreach ($result as $obj)
{
    // Here you can access to every object value in the way that you want
    $result2 = $obj->HTMLStructure;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get a nested object back from your Web-Service. Simplified as PHP code:

```
$result = (object)['Post_Added_Record_ByMenuIDResult' => (object)[
  'HTMLStructure' => "ثبت انجام شد",
  'IsAuthenticated' => 1,
  //...
]];
```

The HTML can be accessed simply like this:

```
$html = $result->Post_Added_Record_ByMenuIDResult->HTMLStructure;

echo $html; // ثبت انجام شد
```

Just like HTMLStructure, you also get the values like IsAuthenticated.